# Adaptive windows mobile application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

What is a good approach to write a windows mobile app that can run on different device, screen resolution, screen size?

In my mind, I'd like to write the form once and be adaptive.

But I'm hearing sometimes that you write the form for different form factors, different screen size, different orientation (portrait/landscape) .... I just find this approach too much work.... there must be a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use docking and anchoring as much as possible, so that you get panels that dock to the top / bottom / middle (fill), and then have controls that are anchored to the left and right.

Sometimes you might have a button or text that you want centered, and in those cases its best to do it in code.

Some additional tips and considerations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms839354.aspx#screen_orientation_awareness_topic4